# In C#, how can I order this list of objects by which item is greater?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a simple class called Team, that looks like this:

```
public class Team
{
     public Team ParentTeam;
     public string Name;
}
```

So it has a Name and a reference to another team that is its Parent Team.

I now have a list of Teams that I am getting back from a function

```
List<Team> list = GetTeamsList();
```

Given, a few assumptions:

1. All teams have a ParentTeam except one (the top team)
2. Every team returned in the list is part of the same hierarchy and its only a single hierarchy (no 2 teams at the same "level")

I now need to take the results of this function and order the list by the hierarchy

So imagine we have the following team information:

```
|| Team Name || Parent Team Name ||
||-----------||------------------||   
|| Team A    || Team B           ||   
|| Team B    || Team C           ||   
|| Team C    || Team D           ||   
|| Team D    || null             ||
```

but the GetTeamsList() function returns the teams in any random order.  For example, it might come back list this:

```
 var teamA = GetTeamA();
 var teamB = GetTeamB();
 var teamC = GetTeamC();
 var teamD = GetTeamD();

 List<Team> list = new List() { teamD, teamA, teamB, teamC };
```

where I need to reorder this list so it looks like this:

```
 List<Team> list = new List() { teamA, teamB, teamC, teamD };
```

How could I reorder a list into the "correct" order based on the team hierarchy?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `GetTeamsList` and also C# compilable code to initialize the teams with the full hierarchy? I would like to be able copy, paste and run your code to see your issue.

Comment: Do two teams ever have the same parent? If so then is there a way to decide which one comes first?

Comment: Because if there is not, then you don't have a "correct order". You are describing a *lattice*, and lattices do not necessarily have a *total order*. You use *topological sort* to find a possible order of a lattice.

Comment: WIth your new restrictions, you have a *linked list* where the "next" pointer is called "parent" and the head node is the "deepest" team and the top team is the tail node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several of the solutions given so far are *correct*, and all of them are at least quadratic in the number of teams; they will be inefficient as the number of teams grows large.

Here's a solution which is (1) linear, (2) shorter, and (3) easier to understand than some of the other solutions so far:

```
static IEnumerable<Team> SortTeams(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
{
  var lookup = teams.ToDictionary(t => t.ParentTeam ?? new Team());
  var current = teams.Single(t => t.ParentTeam == null);
  do
    yield return current;
  while (lookup.TryGetValue(current, out current));
}
```

This produces the sequence in the reverse of the order you want, so put a Reverse on the end of the call if you want it in the other order:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", SortTeams(teams).Reverse().Select(t => t.Name)));
```

The "dummy" team is there because a dictionary does not allow a key to be null.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:

```
public class Team
    {
        public Team ParentTeam;
        public string Name;

        int Level
        {
            get
            {
                int i = 0;
                Team p = this.ParentTeam;
                while (p != null)
                {
                    i++;
                    p = p.ParentTeam;
                }
                return i;
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<Team> Sort(IEnumerable<Team> list)
        {
            return list.OrderBy(o => o.Level);
        }
    }
```

Of course, if there are Teams with equal level, you might use another criteria to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
static IEnumerable<Team> GetOrdered(IEnumerable<Team> teams)
{
    var set = teams as HashSet<Team> ?? new HashSet<Team>(teams);
    var current = teams.First(t => t.Parent == null);

    while (set.Count > 1)
    {
        yield return current;
        set.Remove(current);
        current = set.First(t => t.Parent == current);
    }

    yield return set.Single();
}
```

This gives you the reversed order, so you should call `Reverse()` to get the order you are asking for.

Comment: Suggestions: Instead of `.Where(t => ...).First()`, use `.First(t => ...)` (two places). In the first line, use `var set = teams as HashSet<Team> ?? new HashSet<Team>(teams);`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right you are! Thanks, updated code. I always keep forgetting `First`, `Last`, `Count`, etc., have an overload that takes a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the ascendants of the null team, defining an extension

```
    public static IEnumerable<Team> FindAscendants(this IEnumerable<Team> l, Team from)
    {
        Team t = l.FirstOrDefault(x => 
            (x.ParentTeam?.Name ?? "").Equals(from?.Name ?? ""));
        return new List<Team>() { t }.Concat(t != null ?
            l.FindAscendants(t) : Enumerable.Empty<Team>());
    }
```

and reverse the order of the null team's ascendants

```
list.FindAscendants(null).Reverse().Skip(1)
```

Edit

*Alternative* version of the extension with `yield return`

```
    public static IEnumerable<Team> FindAscendants(this IEnumerable<Team> l, Team from)
    {
        Team t = l.FirstOrDefault(x => 
            (x.ParentTeam?.Name ?? "").Equals(from?.Name ?? ""));
        yield return t;
        if (t != null)
            foreach (Team r in l.FindAscendants(t))
            {
                yield return r;
            }
    }
```

Edit 2

In terms of the most *efficient* solution, a *dictionary* is the key.
As you can see now, there is *no* longer need to *reverse* the order.
So an optimized version would be

```
    public static IEnumerable<Team> FindDescendandOptimized(this List<Team> l, Team from)
    {
        int count = l.Count;
        var dic = l.ToDictionary(x => x.ParentTeam?.Name??"");
        Team start = dic[from?.Name??""];
        Team[] res = new Team[count];
        res[count - 1] = start;
        for (int i = count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            start = dic[start.Name];
            res[i] = start;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

with a test case and usage

```
        List<Team> list = new List<Team>();
        Team team = new Team();
        team.Name = "0";
        list.Add(team);
        for (int i = 1; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            team = new Team();
            team.Name = i.ToString();
            team.ParentTeam = list.Last();
            list.Add(team);
        }
        list.Reverse();
        Console.WriteLine("Order List of " + list.Count +" teams");
        Console.WriteLine("order is " + (TestOrder(list) ? "ok" : "ko"));
        list.Shuffle();
        Console.WriteLine("Shuffled List");
        Console.WriteLine("order is " + (TestOrder(list) ? "ok" : "ko"));
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        var res = list.FindDescendandOptimized(null);
        list = res.ToList();
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Reordered List");
        Console.WriteLine("order is " + (TestOrder(list) ? "ok" : "ko"));
        Console.WriteLine("Benchmark ms: " + (end - start).TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

where the test check is

```
    static bool TestOrder(List<Team> list)
    {
        int tot = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++)
        {
            if (!list[i].Name.Equals((tot-i-1).ToString()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Edit 3

A *final* consideration, maybe *obvious*.
The absolutely most efficient way would have been to define a *child* team.

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name;
    public Team ParentTeam;
    public Team ChildTeam;
}
```

appropriately filled like below

```
            team.ParentTeam = list.Last();
            list.Last().ChildTeam = team;
```

to enable an immediate reordering

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        var res = list.OrderByChild(); //list.FindDescendandOptimized(null);
        list = res.ToList();
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Reordered List");
```

with a direct link

```
    public static IEnumerable<Team> OrderByChild(this List<Team> l)
    {
        int count = l.Count;
        Team start = l.First(x => x.ParentTeam == null);
        Team[] res = new Team[count];
        res[count - 1] = start;
        for (int i = count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            start = start.ChildTeam;
            res[i] = start;
        }
        return res;
    }
```