# Fastest algorithm for a 'circular linked list builder'

Tags: c#, algorithm, pseudocode

I have two questions:

1) What is the fastest algorithm to put this list in a "connecting" order?
2) Is this an existing problem/algorithm, and what name does it have?

The nodes are always connected in a circular fashion, so my starting ID does not matter.

Given this list:

```
id node1 node2
A  4     9
B  6     1
C  1     3
D  3    10
E  7     2
F  4     2
G  9     8
H 10     5
I  7     5
J  6     8
```

node1 & node2 are not in a specific order so id A can be 4 - 9 as well as 9 - 4.

The output should be this (it doesn't matter if it starts with A, as long as the output is a chain).

```
node ids: 4 - 9 - 8 - 6 - 1 - 3 - 10 - 5 - 7 - 2 - 4
ids:        A   G   J   B   C   D    H   I   E   F
```

(I am writing my code in C#. But pseudo code in any language will do)

Comment: Is the list structure already defined as an array of (id, node1, node2) OR is the list structure to be defined to get the best solution ?

Comment: You are looking for something similar to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42072136/767890). I don't think you can get a better performing algorithm.

Comment: @lemon: it's currently in a database, so I can read it into whatever I want

Comment: @InBetween: Not really. That solution has a parent/child. My data node1/node2 can either be a parent/child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
static IEnumerable<Edge<T>> OrderEdges<T>(this IEnumerable<Edge<T>> edges)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    Debug.Assert(edges.Any());
    var map = new Dictionary<T, Edge<T>>();

    foreach (var e in edges)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(e.Node1))
        {
            Debug.Assert(!map.ContainsKey(e.Node2));
            map.Add(e.Node2, e);
        }
        else
        {
            map.Add(e.Node1, e);
        }
    }

    var current = edges.First();
    var orderedEdges = new HashSet<Edge<T>>();

    while (true)
    {
        orderedEdges.Add(current);
        yield return current;

        if (orderedEdges.Count == map.Count)
            break;

        var next = map[current.Node2];
        current = orderedEdges.Contains(next) ? map[current.Node1] : next;
    }
}
```

Where the `Edge<T>` class is simply:

```
class Edge<T> where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    public T Node1 { get; }
    public T Node2 { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Edge(string name, T node1, T node2)
    {
        Name = name;
        Node1 = node1;
        Node2 = node2;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

If we run this little guy:

```
var edges = new List<Edge<int>>() {
    new Edge<int>("A", 4, 9), new Edge<int>("B", 6, 1),
    new Edge<int>("C", 1, 3), new Edge<int>("D", 3, 10),
    new Edge<int>("E", 7, 2), new Edge<int>("F", 4, 2),
    new Edge<int>("G", 9, 8), new Edge<int>("H", 10, 5),
    new Edge<int>("I", 7, 5), new Edge<int>("J", 6, 8) };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" -> ", edges.OrderEdges()));
```

We get the expected result:

```
A -> G -> J -> B -> C -> D -> H -> I -> E -> F
```

Do note that this solution presupposes that the input data is well formed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're looking for [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Comment: It's related, but my input only has one node connected to two, and not more.

Comment: so you mean, there will be always a solution ? that means you just need to simulate 1-way loop to construct your answer.

Comment: Yes, the most efficient algorithm for creating a loop assuming it there will always be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it is some named math problem. Here is pseudo code, which allows you to solve problem in O(N) manner (complexity and memory usage).

1) Create array (we suppose that nodes have unique IDs from range [0..N-1]. And fill it with nodes (node with id should be placed at id position)

2) choose any Node and push it in separate list (it will contain Node in "circular" order). Last Node in that list will be named as processed Node.

3) iterate from 1 to N -1 at each step choose not traversed  neighbor of processed Node. Push such not traversed node  into circular list. Continue process

Note: checking on "not traversed" property can be performed in O(1) way. Just see, where it is already present in circular list. It should be neighbor of last (processed) node

Main disadvantage - assumption of such algorithm is existence the only Euler path.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but this requires to iterate the list a lot of times. I was hoping for something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal using a dictionary (hash table) for calculations.

I have named "cell" a row of the sheet provided in the question (but we don't know your data structure).

It seems to be O(n) as dictionaries provide O(1) retrieval.

All this presume that the initial data are consistent to the problem (as I understood it, at least).

The code is in C# and commented. Tell me if the comments are not enough explanations.

```
class Program
{
    class Cell
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Node1 { get; set; }
        public int Node2 { get; set; }

        public int Min { get { return Math.Min( Node1, Node2 ); } }

        public Cell( string name, int node1, int node2 )
        {
            Id = name;
            Node1 = node1;
            Node2 = node2;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Id + "(" + Node1.ToString() + "," + Node2.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var A = new Cell( "A", 4, 9 );
        var B = new Cell( "B", 6, 1 );
        var C = new Cell( "C", 1, 3 );
        var D = new Cell( "D", 3, 10 );
        var E = new Cell( "E", 7, 2 );
        var F = new Cell( "F", 4, 2 );
        var G = new Cell( "G", 9, 8 );
        var H = new Cell( "H", 10, 5 );
        var I = new Cell( "I", 7, 5 );
        var J = new Cell( "J", 6, 8 );

        var cells = new List<Cell>() { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J };

        // A dictionary to store the cells corresponding to each node values
        Dictionary<int, List<Cell>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<Cell>>();

        // Add all the cells to the dictionary
        foreach ( var cell in cells )
            AddCell( dict, cell );

        // Start with arbitrary first cell and remove it from the dictionary
        var currentCell = GetCell( dict, A.Node1 );
        RemoveCell( dict, currentCell );

        // The result is a list of cells initialized with the first cell
        var result = new List<Cell>() { currentCell };

        // Calculation loop
        bool doContinue = true;
        while ( doContinue )
        {
            // Tries to get a next cell from the node1 of current cell...
            var nextCell = GetCell( dict, currentCell.Node1 );

            // ... or if not found, tries to get it from node2
            if ( nextCell == null )
                nextCell = GetCell( dict, currentCell.Node2 );

            if ( nextCell == null )
            // If not found, we stop
            {
                doContinue = false;
            }
            else
            // If found
            {
                // Add the next cell to the result
                result.Add( nextCell );
                // Remove the cell
                RemoveCell( dict, nextCell );
            }

            // The next cell becomes the current cell
            currentCell = nextCell;
        }

    }

    // Adding a cell puts the cell against its two nodes values
    static void AddCell( Dictionary<int, List<Cell>> dict, Cell cell )
    {
        List<Cell> cells = null;
        if ( dict.TryGetValue( cell.Node1, out cells ) == false )
        {
            cells = new List<Cell>();
            dict[cell.Node1] = cells;
        }
        cells.Add( cell );
        if ( dict.TryGetValue( cell.Node2, out cells ) == false )
        {
            cells = new List<Cell>();
            dict[cell.Node2] = cells;
        }
        cells.Add( cell );
    }

    // Gets a cell from a node value
    static Cell GetCell( Dictionary<int, List<Cell>> dict, int node )
    {
        var cell = null as Cell;
        var cells = dict[node];

        if ( cells.Count > 0 )
            cell = cells.First();

        return cell;
    }

    // Removes a cell from the dictionary for both node1 and node2 entries.
    static void RemoveCell( Dictionary<int, List<Cell>> dict, Cell cell )
    {
        dict[cell.Node1].Remove( cell );
        dict[cell.Node2].Remove( cell );
    }
}
```

Comment: That can be done with an array instead of a dictionary and may have a better performance. Also, we could use the fact that the List<Cell> in the dictionary can only have a count of 2. I will not rewrite all indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The starting point is a list or array like:

```
 1  {A, 4, 9}  
 2  {B, 6, 1}  
 3  {C, 1, 3}  
 4  {D, 3,10}  
 5  {E, 7, 2}  
 6  {F, 4, 2}  
 7  {G, 9, 8}  
 8  {H,10, 5}  
 9  {I, 7, 5}  
10  {J, 6, 8}
```

If we can change this into a list or array like this:

```
 1  {C, 1, 3}  
 2  {F, 2, 4}  (nodes swapped)
 3  {D, 3,10}  
 4  {A, 4, 9}  
 5  {I, 5, 7}  (nodes swapped)
 6  {B, 6, 1}  
 7  {E, 7, 2}  
 8  {J, 8, 6}  (nodes swapped)
 9  {G, 9, 8}  
10  {H,10, 5}
```

which is ordered according to node1, then we can read this list or array as a linked list:

```
start with item 1:  {C, 1, 3}
read node2: 3
skip to item 3:     {D, 3,10}
read node2: 10
skip to item 10:    {H,10, 5}
...
skip to item 6:     {B, 6, 1}
read node2: 1
end of list

result: C D H I E F A G J B
```

Creating this second version of the list can be done in-place, by swapping items in the list, or by copying items to a new list (if you have the space).

The only thing to look out for is that sometimes you may have to swap the two nodes. When re-ordering in-place, this could go like this:

```
look at item 1:     {A, 4, 9}  
  if item 4 has a node1 different from 4, swap item 1 and 4  
  else, change item 1 to {A, 9, 4} and swap item 1 and 9
  (-> item 1 and 4 swapped)    

while current item is already in-place, skip to next
(-> stay at item 1)

look at new item 1: {D, 3,10}  
  if item 3 has a node1 different from 3, swap item 1 and 3  
  else, change item 1 to {D,10, 3} and swap item 1 and 10
  (-> item 1 and 3 swapped)

while current item is already in-place, skip to next
(-> item 1 is now {C, 1, 3}, so skip to item 2)

...
```

When creating a new list or array, this should be even simpler:

```
look at item 1:     {A, 4, 9}  
  if new list has no item 4, copy item 1 as item 4 to the new list
  else, change item 1 to {A, 9, 4} and copy as item 9 to the new list
move to next item
```

As you can see, there is no need to iterate over the list multiple times; every item is swapped or copied once, and its destination is determined by its node1 or node2.

---

UPDATE

I just realised that the number of steps to order the items may be (much) greater than described above. If e.g. you start by moving {A,4,8} to location 4 and {B,5,9} to location 5, and then you encounter {C,4,5}, you're stuck. You would then have to swap {C,4,5} with one of the other two items, swap the nodes in the other item, and move that into place. That new location may itself already be taken, and so on, so there would be no way of knowing which of the two options is the lesser evil. In the worst case scenario the number of swaps would be close to N<sup>2</sup>.

---

UPDATE 2

The problem mentioned above can of course be solved by storing the items as a doubly linked list. When you encounter e.g. {A,4,8}, you store {A,8} as item 4 and {A,4} as item 8, then for {B,5,9} you store {B,9} is item 5 and {B,5} as item 9, and then for {C,4,5}, you add to the already stored items, so that item 4 becomes {A,8,C,5} and item 5 becomes {B,9,C,4}. You can then traverse the doubly linked list in both directions. This will increase the work that needs to be done and the space used, but it is still linear to the number of items in the list.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'm not really sure there is always a node1+1, meaning that my id's are more "random" than the example. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @frankhommers If the id space is not too large, you could just use a sparse array; say the id's are 16-bit integers, then you'd need the space for 65.536 items, however many items there actually are. If you don't have the space, maybe some sort of hashing of the id into a smaller space may be possible?

Comment: @frankhommers I just realised that my suggestion works well enough with your example input, but is not guaranteed to be efficient with all input (see update).

Comment: @frankhommers I added a workaround for the problem mentioned in the update.